# Possible failure to recognise new RAM

Tags: memory, windows-10-preview

[image: http://i.imgur.com/n6Rp7iD.png]

What does this mean?

I recently added a second 4gb module to my laptop, and far as I can tell from general use, my computer isn't able to handle any more tasks than the day before. Is it not using the memory or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the 32Bit Windows 10 Technical Preview which can't use the full 8GB of RAM. Download the 64Bit ISO and install the 64Bit Version of Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek look at the DxDiag output for Operating system. Here it is written that he sues 32Bit version of Build 9879.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. Shame there's no way around that. So, having a 32-bit machine, I'd have to dual-boot Win7 to make use of the full 8gb?

Comment: do what I told you. Install the 64Bit Win10 Preview.

Comment: Dont be rude. You are here to offer answers, not to order people. --- Pretty sure you can't run 64-bit O/S on 32-bit architecture.

Comment: I'm not rude, your I5 is a 64Bit CPU so you can install a 64Bit Windows very easily...

Comment: You sure? How can you tell? I assumed it was 32-bit because when I bought the computer it had a 32-bit version of Win7 installed.

Comment: Well. I just figured out how to check. Of course you're correct. Thanks for the suggestion I'll go ahead and install 64-bit version now.